# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] With browser based location fall back?

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation

I am doing some coding on my localhost, and also testing via my Phone and Tablet.

I planed on using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get users ip for geoip coding. 
however when using mobile phone and localhost I am getting the wrong IP.
I tried using jquery to get geolocation however I am unable to insert the lat and lon in to a weblink. 
At this time I am using this to overcome my problem and get IP lat and lon for another API.

```
$b = '192.168.1.1';
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $b)
{
    $response = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=18.252.235.89');
    $area = json_decode($response, true);
}
else
{
    $response = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    $area = json_decode($response, true);
};
```

I am using the above code to get lat and lon and insert it in to

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='.$area["geoplugin_city"],$area["geoplugin_region"].'&APPID=000000
```

However this only works on my local machine and not on mobile devices, and it is a lot of work for just getting lat and lon; and using an API to get another API info is just wrong in my mind.

Is there away I can use jquery or some form of browser location for everything?
My goal is to get the visitors lat and lon place it in to the openweathermap.org api.

I hope I have provided the information everyone will need to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently developped a client-side solution (based on the IP address). It's called [userinfo.io](http://userinfo.io)

Basically, you would insert this script in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/userinfo/1.0.0/userinfo.min.js"></script>
```

And get a javascript object describing your user:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
UserInfo.getInfo(function(data) {
  console.log(data.position.latitude); // That's your latitude
  console.log(data.position.longitude); // That's your longitude
  // There are plenty of other information in the "data" object
}, function(err) {
  // the "err" object contains useful information in case of an error
});
</script>
```

It can be a good alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

it's fairly easy to get GeoLocation data from the browser using JavaScript.

If I understand your question correctly, using PHP to get this data will definitely not work for you as it will always get the servers information.

Comment: I guess the issue I am having is taking the lat and lon from the JavaScript and placing it in to the openweathermap.org api link!

Comment: skype me: mattsbi and I'll help you out quick. Otherwise I think you'll need to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try browser embedded HTML5 Geolocation API which will give you latitude and longitude of the current position? However, I would not recommend any browser specific API for this.

For not getting IP address, are you using your static IP addresss to point your server?

If you are using geoplugin API just for getting lat, lng for user's IP address, I think that won't give you much accurate results always. If IP is tracked incorrectly, then all following action results also become invalid, hence the weather data you receive at last as I understood.

I think a better approach would be to find user's lat, lng in client side using HTML5 GeoLocation and sending them to your php proxy which will call weather API and give back necessary results. You can accomplish this using AJAX. If that weather API has not CORS restrictions or support jsonp, you can directly call to weather API bypassing a separate proxy.

If HTML5 GeoLocation fails initially, you can use some fallback options like Maxmind API and Google Map APIs.